# Imperative vs functional kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I want to branch my input Kafka streams based on some criteria.  With imperative programming I can do that with the following code.

```
KStream<String, AirSupportRequest> stream = builder.stream("location_support");

Predicate<String, LocationSupport> northAmerica = (k, v) -> v.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("NORTHAMERICA");
Predicate<String, LocationSupport> asia = (k, v) -> v.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("ASIA");
KStream<String, LocationSupport>[] kStreams = stream.branch(northAmerica, asia);
kStreams[0].foreach(
      (key, value) -> {
          System.out.println(key + " : " + value.toString());
      });
```

Trying the same thing with SpringCloud Stream Kafka Binder.  Here is my code

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, AirSupportRequest>, KStream<String, AirSupportRequest>[]> filterByLocation() {
   Predicate<String, LocationSupport> northAmerica = (k, v) -> v.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("NORTHAMERICA");
   Predicate<String, LocationSupport> asia = (k, v) -> v.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("ASIA");

   return input -> input
    .branch(northAmerica, asia);
}
```

Now how do I access the kstream array returned by the filterByLocation()?

Comment: `return input -> input.branch(northAmerica, asia)[0].foreach(..)` perhaps? I mean I am just following the logic from the first example.

Comment: That works.  I can also do return input -> input.filter(northAmerica).foreach(...).  
But the syntax I am looking for a way to call filterByLocation() method from some other class.  For example,
    @Component
    public class TestLocation {
      public void someMethod() {
         //call filterByLocation()
      }
    }